# Change userModel for authentication CAKE 3

Tags: authentication, cakephp-3.x

I need to implement user authentication with the table and model with another name, different of users (users_php->UsersPhp or another name). I see that exists the setting in 
BaseAuthenticate->$_defaultConfig->userModel into vendor, and if I change userModel there, all it works, but this not possible em production. Help me in to implement this change in anywhere into my src or config.

I don’t finded this answer here at platform.

Comment: Why is it "not possible on production"?

Comment: Why I don't send the vendor folder to server, I install the dependencies via composer...

Comment: You're using the Auth component, right? Please show your code where you configure that, like `$this->Auth->config(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Greg Schmidt,
Your question answered my question, below my answer

AppController->initialize

```
$this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
   'Form' => ['userModel' => 'MyNewModel']
]);
```